# Brave Browser showing 80% CPU in tskmgr but I'm not connected to the internet also Network Config issue

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, connection, internet-connection, tethering

Having a little network config issues and a web browser jacking my CPU while disconnected has me stumped. 
Tethering to Asus laptop windows 10 pro,latest,pretty clean and error free. Web pages loading a little slow today. Consistently clean on DISM, SFC scans. I cleared win-sock,flush DNS, all that good stuff.

Have had issues in past with 100% CPU due, I believe, to those two windows updates. (That and I'm making movies on two programs at the same time,watching music video files,trading crypto with 8 windows open etc etc) It's like time broker can't keep up with the demand and has a melt down. Open task manager and system interrupt is froze at the top,red lined at 100%. Once I end 1 or 2 instances of time broker it unfreezes.Also I have to restart explorer often as I lose icons (more on the desktop but in folders too) and if my mouse crosses "open with" in the context menu I have to cntrl alt del (as it freezes) Usually taskmngr will open and I can restart explorer. 
Not sure if it was something I did or a Microsoft patch but that issue appears to be fixed.
I actually reinstalled windows at one point and basically replicated the issues. Once I installed the windows updates it cleared up 95% of them.
Sorry probably TMI but I figured it may relate.
Everything is working fine now.... Last few days I've been getting way higher speeds. Downloading say a movie normally would max DL speed 75-80 K tops with no limit set.Suppose to have 1 GB speed but I'm rural and rely on one tower which I can barely get 1-2 bars 4g thru so I figured that was the issue. The speed increase comes/goes? not sure...still figuring it out. It doesn't speed up web page load times at all and often the page "resets" and I have to repeatedly reset crypto chart settings back the way I had them. They use to "keep alive" which was way quicker. I've found that "page ahead" setting. One in internet options and one  in brave setting but neither help. Is the setting for that in google:config or something? I can't recall. Please pass it on if you know.

The other day I had big darker green circles with a check mark in them on most of my desktop folders. That has happened twice in the last few days. (it's not google drive,it's not even installed) I ran
 ie4uinit.exe -show
 and they went away. I can't find any sync settings which is what I thought it might be....maybe in an update or maybe my phone is trying to sync?? As u can prob tell, I'm no expert.

When I connect with Pdanet,I use the direct connect/WiFi SSID but may have a config issue.It's a bit of a complicated set-up... at least for me.
I'm using Hamachi & Privoxy,tethering using data from my phone  ending with pretty secure wi-fi so I'm sure something could be amiss. The WiFi connection say "No internet,secure" even though it shows 1.2bil/560mil byte sent/received. MS settings says I'm connected to an unknown, private, local net. with no traffic. PDAnet says connected v4 internet  0 packets sent/rec. Oddly, and this may be where the speed issue lies,Pdanet has 1G speed & has been running for one hour while the WiFi direct has 72.2mbps and has been running nearly 5 hours. On top of that Hamachi sits working quietly....no network,no internet 10GB speed with 3mil packets sent & 40,000 received  Not sure how it did that with no connection lol. The only current config on Privoxy is the Hamachi IP and port which it "binds" to. I was port forwarding the internet IP in Privoxy but PDAnet? is doing it automatically now.

I get random "reconnected" popups 6-10 times a day or maybe more.Also, I have to restart my phone maybe once or twice in a full day on lost connection.Just drops,says nothing.The reconnected's never delays my progress so maybe it's just a momentary disconnect? It may be getting interference from nearby Zosi wired security system which I haven't been able to configure the IP / networking on it for online viewing.The Zosi NVR sounds like a drive going bad and seems to mimic what I'm doing on the PC (like it's working at opening a page for me,then the page opens and it goes quiet.) Reminds me of the sound my "Emachines" (back in the 98SE days) made when I needed to run the defrag. My friend, who is really computer literate, thought the sound was coming from my laptop and warned me my drive was going bad.
The Zosi's drive is fine and passed all the tests which makes me think somehow there is interference.
I've turned it off a few times but forget to keep an eye on the connection. Maybe if I pin a note on my shirt I can get that done.

I get two warnings often when connecting. One that it couldn't verify DNS?? and that if I don't have internet try rebooting. It seems to have trouble figuring out/configuring/getting/finding(?) the DNS The other is that it's connected to my phone but it doesn't appear to have internet service available,check and reconnect.  Easiest fix is to restart the phone,restart Pdanet and usually it will connect without even turning the Pdanet prog on,on the PC. Could having the PDA app on the PC and using the direct connect be a conflict in itself?
I've reinstalled Pda/Hamachi/Privoxy/net adapters/update drivers/sfc/dism
Now tonight as I'm trying to do this process I had task manager open and brave browser was at 80% CPU. My phone wasn't on and there is no other service out here it could have connected to.

DAMN! Writing this out reminded me that I enabled brave browser updates in services earlier. Maybe it was updating when I disconnected and continued for a bit? I have background continuation off but I assume it would still be receiving data momentarily after I disconnected. Must be it.

Well hey! thanks everyone for helping me figure it out .

I'd appreciate any advice on getting my internet to stay connected and at a reasonable speed though.

I'd also love to know how I accidentally got my 1 GB speed if anyone has any ideas. I'm using 100 GB tethering a month it's data so supposedly they can't see it but maybe I'm being throttled all the time . They've relaxed their policies a bit with the virus going around and bandwidth usage rising.
 Lastly I have a couple Netgear N600 dual band routers WNDR3400v2. I was told it may be a better way to set up my tethered connection and security cameras. If so, a link to how to do that properly would be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance, Rob H.

below is my ipconfig.

SHOULD PDANET'S DNS SERVER be the same as the wireless LAN'S?

Node Type  Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled No
   WINS Proxy Enabled No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Media State Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Hamachi
   Description  LogMeIn Hamachi Virtual Ethernet Adapter

DHCP Enabled. Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled  Yes
   IPv6 Address 2620:XXXXXX:7c63(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address fe80::d552XXXXX:db37%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address 25.77.124.99(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask 255.0.0.0

Default Gateway  2620:9b::1900:1
   DHCP Server  25.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID  84037874
   DHCPv6 Client DUID 00-01-00-01-XXXXXXX3F-49-C1-18-A5
   DNS Servers . fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. Disabled

Ethernet adapter PdaNet Broadband Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix 
   Description PdaNet Broadband Adapter

DHCP Enabled Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled  Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address fe80::39e8:XXXXXX511d:be13%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address 10.1.19.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask  255.255.255.0
      Default Gateway  10.1.19.1
   DHCP Server  10.1.19.1
   DHCPv6 IAID 134XXXX22
   DHCPv6 Client DUID 00-01-00-01-25-C0-XXXXX-C1-18-A5
   DNS Servers 8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. Disabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1: + 
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10: -SAME-

Media State Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix
   Description  Microsoft WiFi Direct Virtual Adapter

DHCP Enabled. Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:   Connection-specific DNS Suffix 
   Description  Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
      DHCP Enabled. Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled  Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address  fe80::9fb:e46fXXXXX:258%19(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address 192.168.49.56(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask  255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway 192.168.49.1
   DHCP Server  192.168.49.1
   DHCPv6 IAID  223618846
   DHCPv6 Client DUID 00-01-00-01-25-C0-XXXXXX-C1-18-A5
   DNS Servers  192.168.49.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip Disabled

Comment: Still having some issues. Mainly DNS. The reconnects were caused by voltage surge from a mini fridge kicking on. Some how my privoxy gets corrupted and fails to start(about every 30 days). I simply delete it,replace it,set the hamachi IP/port in main config and it works again. I think it's some windows automatic maintenance as I've had other programs delete something out of the privoxy folder,can't find log file maybe??